# IE11 + Bootstrap vue Issue focusable elements have multiple black border when visited

Tags: bootstrap-vue

Hi @all  Need help to resolve a IE11 / Edge + Bootstrap vue + b-modal issue.We are seeing multiple black lines when we focus / active on button, input boxes (Please refer to screenshot below). We were able to replicate in bootstrap vue sanbox also (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/)Same happens in our project too which has below dependencies

"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.2" // Able to replicate in sandbox too

Steps to replicate the issue:
hover or focus on elements
[Sanbox issue replicated 1][2]
[Sanbox issue replicated 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVu8x.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any addons/extensions that may be causing any issues or conflicts?  I do not see the issue on IE11 (docs site is using BootstrapVue v2.1.0):

[image]

Comment: I changed the screenshot in previous please review. The issue is replicable in sandbox and latest bootstrap vue tooo
steps to replicate
1) Hover on elements which is inside modal
2) Can see multiple lines
Sample HTML is available at [Sample code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SridhanyaG/bootstrapvueissue/master/VueBootstrapVue.html)
Please download and run it is IE
**Note: https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js is used in this sample

Comment: A css to turn of this animations would help. Also raise a jira in their board
https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4422